# Android hierarchy for XPath to interact with specific item

Tags: android, xpath, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm new to automatization, Android, Selenium, Appium and xpath, too. I know it's suck a great beggining.

I write tests for Android devices, but the application I have to test have a lot of costum views. I found out the best way to interact with these custom  items is to put an "**android:contentDescription**" field in the Views. My only question is how to get access to the element with have a specified `contentDescription`? This is az android specific question, I'm not even sure that the `content-desc` is the field I'm looking for.

I have the hierarchy provided by Android UI Animator Viewer:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaymk.png

The ways i've tried:

- xpath: `//*[contains(@android:contentDescription,'example text')]`
- I was able to get access by finding them as an `ImageView`, but as I mentioned I need to work with custom Views

My code looks like somtihng like this:

`driver.findElementByXPath("//*[constains(@content-desc,'Login')]").click();`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try using Accessibility labels or the UIAutomator locator strategy.
Here's [Appium's documentation on those.](http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.2.0/?java#toc_59)

Your xpath is incorrect. It should be: `"//android.widget.ImageView[@content-desc='Login']"`

Here's some pseudocode of what you should do:

```
login_image = driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.ImageView[@content-desc='Login']"); // Gets you the WebElement

print login_image.getClass(); // Just for debugging, make sure it's not nil/null

login_image.click(); // Click on it!
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not my thing :( I'm sure my xpath is correct it's just a general version of yours. My problem is I have no clue how android works in this case. Does it even use this (I guess) field (content-desc or something else) or should I chose an other way to get access to the elements.

Comment: Edited to add other locator strategies

Comment: Thanks, your edit helped a Lot!
If somebody else may need this I leave it here:
This was the key document: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/spec-draft.md?repo=mobile&r=1b90597cfde5f2deab58c506d4867fa1d165709a